# Bash shell script: f: command not found

Tags: bash, syntax-error, sh

I'm writing a script that finds all .gz files under every directory. Code below works in terminal but crashes when executing the shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find all directories in Output directory
dirs=($(find ~/Documents/MainDir/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/Output -type d)) && wait

# Concatenate all .gz files in a dir, unzip gzip & remove unwanted files
for dir in $dirs
do
    if f in $(find . -name "*.gz")
    then
        cd $dir; cat *.gz > output.gz && gunzip -d output.gz && find . -type f -not -name 'output' | xargs rm
    fi
done
```

At first I tried to run the script without 'do' which resulted in

```
syntax error near unexpected token `if'
`if f in $(find . -name "*.gz")'
```

After adding do I'm getting the following error:

```
f: command not found
```

How to fix this problem? Thx

Comment: Use http://www.shellcheck.net/ and it's `for ... in` not `if ... in`

Comment: andlrc, `if f in $(find . -name "*.gz")` **is not a proper form** of an `if` _statement_!  Have a look at [7.1. Introduction to if](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) and [Conditional (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming))

Comment: @andlrc, I've never seen the _keyword_ `in` used in conjunction with the _keyword_ `if` as in the OP, nor is it used in either of the two links of my previous comment. Unless you can provide a valid _boolean condition_ `if` statement that is also using the _keyword_ `in`, in it, that I can test with ... then I have to stand by my previous comments.  I'm certainly willing to lean however I fail to see anything correct in `if f in $(find . -name "*.gz")` as a correct and or proper form of an `if` _statement_ !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114051/discussion-between-andlrc-and-user3439894).

Comment: `wait` doesn't do anything useful in the first line (unless there are background jobs started previously and not shown); the assignment doesn't complete until the command substitution does, and there are no background jobs involved.

Comment: @user3439894 `if echo in foo bar ; then echo yes ; else echo no ; fi` is perfectly valid syntax (it prints `in foo bar` followed by `yes`). In this context, `in` is not treated as a keyword; it's simply an argument passed to the `echo` command, and the status of that command is tested. It's almost certainly not what the OP *intended*, but it's not a syntax error. Note that the OP reports that the code in the question doesn't report a syntax error; it says `f: command not found`. He only gets a syntax error when he removes the `do` (which is syntactically required for the `for`).

Comment: @Keith Thompson, The command `if f in $(find . -name "*.gz")` is producing the error `f: command not found` so obviously the OP's use in this case is not correct!  That's really then only point I'm trying to make!

Comment: @user3439894: I never said it wasn't correct. I said it's not a syntax error.

Comment: Your title is misleading. The title (currently) mentions a syntax error message "syntax error near unexpected token `if'", but that doesn't apply to the code in your question. You only get a syntax error when you delete the `do` keyword (which is required to go along with the `while` so *of course* it's a syntax error). The real problem is the "`f: command not found`" error. Please update the title (and there's no need to say anything about removing the `do` or what happens if you do so).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this could be to have a more advanced use of the find command, taking advantage of the predicates and the -exec options, which could run a command for each matching file encountered, such as:

```bash
rm $dir/output.gz
find $dir -name "*.gz" -a ! -name "output.gz" -exec sh "cat {} > $dir/output.gz && rm {}" \;
```

(not verified code)

You should take account of @tripleee's wise comment on the `-exec` option and keep it a single command, using a sub shell invocation to handle complex processing.

Comment: No, you can't use `&&` or other shell metacharacters inside the `-exec`. A common workaround is to `-exec sh '...' _ {} \;` where you can use any shell syntax inside the single quotes.